# "Create New View" changes the active(highlighted) tab

Tags: tab, admin

There are 12 tabs in my custom app and 4 of them are VF tabs. The rest of them are all Custom object tabs/Standard Tabs (Reports and Dashboards). Issue is with 2 of the Custom Object tabs - When I click on "Create New View" link after opening the tab, the highlighted tab changes to some other random value instead of staying on the current Tab.
For eg. 
1. I click on Orders tab.
2. I click on "Create New View" link within the tab
3. I get the page for creating a new view for Orders (as is apparent from the options provided to me) - but now the highlighted tab is say for eg. Accounts (or any other tab!!).

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `tabStyle` attribute on the `<apex:page>` tag? If not, then that's what you need to do.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm

Comment: I am not talking about the VF tabs. Those work just fine. As mentioned, the issue is with the custom object tabs. The example I gave is with Standard objects, but the issue is only with custom object tab - The highlighted tab changes when "Create New View" is clicked.

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't read the question properly. No idea what's causing your actual issue!

Comment: One thing to note is that its working properly in DEV sandbox, but behaving like this in Test. If we say its a deployment issue, then what component would have been missed out while deploying, since this is a standard layout for a custom object?